# C++ casting char into short

Tags: c++, casting, char, type-conversion, short

Pardon me for this newbie question. I recently found that a strange thing when casting char into short. Basically, if the char is overflowed, when casting into short the binary number is prepended with 11111111. If the char is not overflowed, it will be prepended with 00000000.

For example,

```
char a = 130;
short b = (short)a;
printf("%hhx\n", a);
printf("%hx\n", b);
```

prints

```
82
ff82
```

While

```
char a = 125;
short b = (short)a;
printf("%hhx\n", a);
printf("%hx\n", b);
```

prints

```
7d
7d
```

So when doing casting, do variable type and value get checked before deciding what exactly binary number it's casted into (deciding b/w prepending 0xFF or 0x00)? Is there any reason behind this? It seems always doing `(short)a & 0x00FF` would be a good practice?

Comment: You're just seeing the mechanics of signed value extension.

Comment: Two (unrelated) problems: 1) If you ever feel the need to do a C-style cast (like `(short)a`) in C++ then you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong; And 2) Why are you using `printf` in C++ code?

Comment: More related to your issue, it's implementation specific (i.e. up to the compiler) if `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: The cast in the code is irrelevant; the compiler will do that conversion without being explicitly told to do it.

Comment: Good practice when doing bit processing is to use types with bits indicated in name. For example uint16_t instead of short or int8_t instead of char. These make it more clear to reader of code that the logic depends on precise bits. Include <stdint.h> for to have these types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on: [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for how negative numbers are encoded in binary.

In a `signed char`, assuming an 8-bit char width and 2's complement arch, a char can hold a value between -128 to +127.

When you say:

```
char a = 130;
```

That's out of range.

130 as integer in 32-bit binary is:  `00000000 00000000 00000000 10000010`

In Hex, it's:  `00 00 00 82`.  That's where your `82` value is coming from.

When `int(130)` is cast to char it's basically just chopping off all by the last byte of bits: `10000010`.

Hence char `a = <binary:10000010>` is `-126` in 2's complement arithmetic.

So when you assign `short b = a`, you're just assigned -126 to a short.

In 2's complement architecture, when a negative number gets promoted to a larger type, it gets "sign extended".  That is, if the most significant bit of the signed char is `1`, then when it gets converted to short, the extra byte is prepended with leading `1`s as well.  That is, `-126` as a 16-bit binary is: `11111111 10000010` or `0xff82`

Try declaring `a` as `unsigned char` and you should get different results.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I'm aware of 2's complement. What I didn't know, as you pointed out, is "sign extention" based on checking the most significant bit of unsigned char.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> char a = 130;
> ```

There's a high chance that `char` is 8 bits on your system, and we can guess based on the output that it is a signed type. In that case, the largest representable value of `char` is 127. 130 is greater than 127, so it isn't representable. In this case, the converted value will be the representable value that is congruent with 130 modulo 128, which is -126. When you convert to the two byte `short`, the value remains the same -126. ff82 is how -126 is represented as a two byte two's complement number.

> It seems always doing (short)a & 0x00FF would be a good practice?

If you did that, then the value of `b` would be different (130) from the value of `a` (-126). Is it a "good practice" to get one result as opposed to another result? That depends on which result you need.

Bit masking only really makes sense with unsigned types.

Assigning an unrepresentable value to a signed integer type rarely makes sense.